# Android on Windows or UWP suggestion

Tags: java, c#, android, uwp

I have an android app in the play store that I use heavily for my job. It is based around LDAP. I could port the app to windows java app, C# Windows Form app or a Universal app because I have the full source and have experience with all of these but I would rather not change the interface (this would be the hardest part of porting it to anything). There is no real reliance on anything specific to Android itself other than the interface. My plan is to use this app on a low end atom PC when on the go so most emulators are not an option and nor do they start fast enough. Xamarin looks interesting but if I am going to use that at all I might as well just port everything over.

Is there some android to windows java interface or wrapper I can use to easily port this to windows? Or is there any fast low end emulator that I can build removing everything my app does not need?

I am open to any and all suggestions be it porting, emulation or 3rd party wrapper. I have searched but am failing to really find anything and have not really been involved in the android side of things much in the last 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

Im going to answer this question based on the assumption that you are looking for the easiest way that would provide a stable way to run your android app on a PC.

Here are a couple of options:

1. You can use the bluestack android emulator available at https://www.bluestacks.com/#gref. This will allows your app to run on top of an emulation layer provided by bluestacks.
2. A virtual machine with an X86 image of android like Remix-OS. You can use virtual box available here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads to run the virtual machine, and you can get the x86 image of Remix-os from here http://www.jide.com/remixos-for-pc.
3. Since you want to use low end hardware, a 3rd option would be to run Remix-OS Natively instead of virtualized and save the resource usage of the host OS. To do this install it along side windows as a dual boot option. You should also use the 32 bit version of Remix-OS since  you are going to be running it on an old machine.

I would reccomend option 3 over 2 or 1 as Remix-OS is fully free unlike bluestacks which uses a freemium model and tends to be more stable and bug free then bluestacks and if you install it natively you will see increased performance.